# OpenId AppAuth Custom redirect uri issue?

Tags: android, android-studio, openid-connect

I am working on play billing libray for this i need authentication , and i am using OpenId AppAuth but i am stucked on redirect Uri . i used dynamic link but not getting any access token from there so where to create this redirect uri to get access token

```
   const REDIRECT_URI =""  // Redirect Uri 

    



    
    private  fun getAuthorizationConfiguration()                                                                                         :AuthorizationServiceConfiguration{
    return AuthorizationServiceConfiguration(
        Uri.parse(OpenIdUtils.AUTH_URL),  // authorization endpoint
        Uri.parse(OpenIdUtils.ACCESS_TOKEN_URL)) }  // authorization token


 private fun authorizationRequest(serviceConfiguration: AuthorizationServiceConfiguration) : AuthorizationRequest {

return AuthorizationRequest.Builder(
    serviceConfiguration, // the authorization service configuration
    OpenIdUtils.CLIENT_ID, // the client ID, typically pre-registered and static
    ResponseTypeValues.CODE, // the response_type value: we want a code
    OpenIdUtils.REDIRECT_URI).setScope(OpenIdUtils.SCOPE)
    .build();
}




 fun  doAuthorization(context  : Context) :Intent {
 val authConfiguration =    getAuthorizationConfiguration()
   val authRequest =  authorizationRequest(authConfiguration)
    val  authService  = AuthorizationService(context);

     authService.performAuthorizationRequest(
         authRequest,
         PendingIntent.getActivity(
             context,
             OpenIdUtils.RC_AUTH,
             Intent(context, DemoActivity::class.java),
             0
         ))

    return  authService.getAuthorizationRequestIntent(authRequest);

}



    

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="https"
                android:host="www.example.com"
                />

        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well there are two stages here:

- Call startActivityForResult with your intent
- Then handle the response and call performTokenRequest to get tokens

But using HTTPS URLs (Claimed HTTPS Schemes) is tricky and you may run into issues that require an interstitial web page in order for the app to receive the login response.

In the early days of getting integrated, you may want to start with a Custom URI Scheme redirect URI of this form, even though it is less secure:

- com.mycompany.myapp:/callback

**HTTPS EXAMPLE**

If you want an Android sample to compare against which uses HTTPS URLs, take a look at these resources of mine:

- [Code Sample you can run on your computer](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.mobilesample.android)
- [AppAuth Code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.mobilesample.android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/authguidance/basicmobileapp/plumbing/oauth/AuthenticatorImpl.kt#L204)
- [Blog Post](https://authguidance.com/2019/09/13/android-code-sample-overview/)

Comment: Thanks man can you recommend me where should i deploy my Login , logout HTML file and callback url